# Solving for numerator in equation with logarithms (Activation Energy Equation)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, chemistry

I'm having trouble solving for k1 in this equation:

ln(0.286/k1) = (100000/8.314)(1/500 - 1/490)

The right side should equal 0.491, which I can calculate just fine, but then the left side gives me trouble. Here's my approach:

ln(0.286/k1) = 0.491 
ln(0.286) - ln(k1) = 0.491 
- ln(k1) = 0.491 - ln(0.286)
- ln(k1) = 1.7426
- k1 = e^1.7426
k1 = -5.7127

The problem is that the answer I'm given in my textbook is k1 = 0.175

I'm not comfortable enough with algebra/logarithms to see where my error is, could someone help me understand it?

Answer (score 1):

(-) ln(k1) = 1.7426
  (-) k1 = e^1.7426

Here's the mistake=>

the second equation should have been 
$1\over k1$ $= e^{1.7426}$

k1=$1\over 5.7127$    => 0.175

Comment: I see! Is this a rule that has a general form?

Comment: - log(k)  =  log($k^{-1}$) = log($1\over k$)

Comment: Oh, of course! Thanks a lot!